# How to Make Raw Data Recognizable in Audacity

Tags: audacity

I want to import a file from Zynaddsubfx. Here are the steps I am taking in Audacity:

File

Import

Raw Data

I pick the file I want, from Zynaddsubfx, which is a .xmz file. The file is imported, but it lasts about a mili-second and all I hear is white noise. How do you change it to something recognizable? Thanks so much for all of your feedback in advance.

Comment: Can you export the xmz file as something else from Zynaddsubfx? Such as a WMV file?

Comment: Possibly related: http://forum.audacityteam.org/viewtopic.php?f=46&t=64733

Comment: I think you are correct in your answer, I looked at your link, and that is exactly what I was trying to do. I guess I have a follow up question- how do you play the file from Zynaddsubfx so that I can record into Audacity?